# Exporting package-level Python symbols in Doxygen

Tags: python, doxygen

In Doxygen, if I have the following code structure:

```
foo/__init__.py
foo/bar.py
```

with `foo/bar.py` containing:

```
def meh():
  """@brief Some cool feature.

  More details...
  """
  print "Hello, world!"
```

and `foo/__init__.py` containing:

```
# Publicly expose "foo.bar.meh" as "foo.meh".
from foo.bar import meh
```

In this scheme, `meh` is in internal `foo.bar` purely for structural
code layout reasons and should appear as `foo.meh` in the public API.

An example of this scheme in action is `os.path` from the standard library which publicly exposes symbols from one of a number of OS-specific implementation modules (which also happen to be available as `os.path.nt` for instance).

---

When I run Doxygen on this source tree, I get `meh` as `foo.bar.meh` and I can't get it as `foo.meh`.

I tried explicitly qualifying `meh` using the [`@fn`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdfn) command but then I get some weird warnings and the function is not in the output.  Using [`@class`](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdclass) for classes creates a situation where I have two `Meh` classes and one has the brief & defailed documentation whereas the other has the methods and other members.  Presumably, Doxygen interprets the `@class` directive as the documentation for a class in another module and does not associate the documentation with the class that follows the special comment block.

---

How can I expose internal module symbols as public package symbols using Doxygen?

---

For the record, this is a very large hybrid C++ and Python code base with tons of Doxygen comments that I'm not interested in converting to reStrcuturedText or Sphinx (on a short term basis, at least).